# How to reload a module (from within the class) if it's an old version

Tags: python

I am trying to reload a class (from within the class) if the version of the class is out of date with what the version should be.

Would the following make sense and work? If not, could you please suggest the correct way to accomplish the above?

```
class MoviesEC2Prices(GenericScript):

    def __init__(self):

        super(MoviesEC2Prices, self).__init__()

        self.exporter = BaseExporter()
        self.ingester = self.exporter.ingester
        self.VERSION = 2

        self.ingester.cursor.execute("SELECT version_id FROM movies_version")
        if self.ingester.cursor.fetchone()[0] != self.VERSION:
            subprocess.call(shlex.split('git pull origin master'))
            reload(ingest)
            reload(ingest.movies_ec2)
            import ingest
            from ingest.movies_ec2 import MoviesEC2Prices
            self = MoviesEC2Prices()
```

What would be the best way to accomplish the above -- that is, if there is a version mis-match, download the code from git and "re-run" the script.

Comment: One solution could be to kill the current process and run a second process that updates the codebase and upon completion, runs the main process again.

Comment: @Vulcan that was my idea...just to do a sys.exit(1) if the codebase is old and re-start the process. But I was hoping there was a way to do this within the code?

Comment: Your solution looks great, but why you execute `import` again after reload? For initilization purpose?

Comment: And BTW, there is a lib to interact with git `GitPython`.

Comment: @Sraw -- do I not need to re-import the modules? Does doing the reload() already do that?

Comment: This is called [monkey patching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977270/monkey-patching-in-python-when-we-need-it) is an SO Q&A about when (not) to use it.

Comment: @David542 Yes, you needn't to re-import it. `reload` does it for you. And further the returned value of `reload` is the new loaded module so that you can bind it to another name.

Comment: @Sraw I see -- what do I need to 'call' then after dong `reload(ingest.movies_ec2)`? Just doing `self = MoviesEC2Prices()` doesn't seem to work -- want to show a correct example in an answer and I can accept that, assuming it works?

Comment: @David542 As @Sraw mentioned, you need to assign the reloaded library back onto its name. So, `ingest = reload(ingest)`.

Comment: You also can't simply redefine `self` (last line of your code), that will only change the local variable `self`, not the global version of the object. You should probably wrap that object in another function, put the updating logic in that function, and call that function (instead of just initializing the object) when you need it.

Comment: Well, I think @ethguo has answered your question. Updating `self` won't affect outside as it is only a local variable. BTW, ethguo, `reload` does re-bind the name. `ingest = reload(ingest)` is redundant.